# how to find the rows of my table in which the value of remaining field is more than zero in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-7

i have a layout that shows all the orders placed in which i have record of paid and remaining amount also , so i am trying to display the background color of rows as red if remaining field data is more than 0 for this i am trying this method

```
public function noBalance() {

    return Order::where('remaining', '>', 0)->first();
}
```

i am creating this in model file of Order
also tried this

```
return Order::where('remaining', '>', 0);
```

and

```
  @foreach ($orders as $order)
          
       <tr style="{{ $order->noBalance() ? 'background-color: lightcoral;' : '' }}">
            (here i am using that function in my allorder.blade.php)                
          <td>{{$order->id}}</td>
          <td>{{$order->client}}</td>
          <td>{{$order->salesmanRelation->employee_name}}</td>
          <td>{{$order->orderBooker->employee_name}}</td>
          <td>{{$order->total_amount}}</td>
          <td>{{$order->paid}}</td>
          <td>{{$order->remaining}}</td>
          <td>{{$order->discount}}</td>
          <td>{{$order->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</td>
          <td><a href="/orders/{{$order->id}}">Detail</a></td>
          <td><a href="/orders/{{$order->id}}/edit">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>                        
     
   @endforeach
```

but after using this all the rows of my table gets light coral not only the rows with the remaining >0

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a field 'remaining' in your database you can access it with:

```
$order->remaining;
```

So your if statement should look like this:

```
{{ $order->remaining > 0 ? 'background-color: lightcoral;' : '' }}
```

And the function noBalance() can be removed.
yes that is the right answer